# How to join two lists together by alternately adding the objects?

Tags: java, list, loops, join, iterator

If I have two lists

```
List<Paper> papers;
List<Paper> papers2;
```

What is the best way to go through them and create a new list where the order is one Paper object from papers then one Paper object from papers2 and so forth until the list ends?

*Edit*
They are different sizes and change according to input

Thank you

Comment: are the lists the same size?

Comment: @ScaryWombat - they are different sizes & change according to input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need to loop as

> 1) go through both Lists together 2) then continue looping through `papers`
>   3) then continue looping through `papers2`

```
 answer = new ArrayList ();
 int i = 0, k = 0;
 while (i < papers.size () &&  k < papers2.size ())
 {
     // add papers.get (i);
     // add papers2.get (k);
     i++;
     k++;
 }

 // this will not be entered if completely looped through papers
 while (i < papers.size ())
 {
     // add papers.get (i);
     i++;
 }

 // this will not be entered if completely looped through papers2
 while (k < papers2.size ())
 {
     // add papers2.get (i);
     k++;
 }
```

Comment: but if i throw both lists together it wont be in the order of one object from paper then one object papers2 then one object from paper then one object from papers2 (etc.)?

Comment: I think my post answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code for altering between 2 string lists l1 and l2. You can have similar logic for list of papers.

```
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i=0,j=0;

        while(i<l1.size() && j<l2.size()){
            res.add(l1.get(i++));
            res.add(l2.get(j++));
        }

        while(i<l1.size()){
            res.add(l1.get(i++));
        }
        while(j<l2.size()){
            res.add(l2.get(j++));
        }

        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < res.size(); j2++) {
            System.out.println(j2 +" : "+res.get(j2));
        }
```